# How to add UIImagePickerController in UiView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

How to add UIImagePickerController in UiView in TabBarApplication

Answer (score 15):

It doesn't matter if you are in a tab, this code goes into the ViewController class for your view

Create a picker when you want one

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
// configure it how you want
```

Add the picker

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Your view controller needs to be declared like

```
@interface YourViewController :  
   UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

And you need to implement

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
```

(the first one should get the image from the info object)

In each of those messages, when done, remove the picker

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Mike is long gone though to accept for your necromancer tag :)

Comment: Badge description says I only need 5 votes -- thanks for the vote.  I've been trying to get necromancer for a while (they shortened the time).

Comment: Does the delegate need to be self?  I want to have the VC that is presenting the `UIPopoverViewController`, which his then presenting the `UIImagePickerController` handle the delegate calls for the picker.  Though I cannot seem to get anything but the NavBar to be presented.

Comment: It can be any class that implements the protocol (UIImagePickerControllerDelegate) -- leave UINavigationController in the UIPopoverViewController